# What does `<>` mean?

Tags: sql-standard, operator

What does `<>` do in the following `WHERE` clause,

```
WHERE posn_id <> rid
```

Comment: I've removed any association with db2 because it has nothing to do with db2 and we don't need one question for every database. Shy of that, it's not a bad question, albeit a bit basic.

Comment: This has *got* to be a duplicate.

Comment: Related: [Authoritative source that <> and != are identical in performance in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/155650/3690)

Comment: @jpmc26: not on dba, but on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/723195/330315 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/5658457/330315 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/43817212/330315 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/13740732/330315 - the problem is: you can't search for `<>` or `!=`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was trying [Symbol Hound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3C%3E+sql&l=&e=&n=&u=dba.stackexchange.com), but it seems like something is wrong with their search when you enter `dba.stackexchange.com` into the site field. (I'd think it would at least come up with a few answers that contain it in their SQL or something, or at least *this* question.) But I still have a hard time believe it's never come up before on the site.

Comment: @jpmc26 https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55748/138184? (or https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/143422/138184)

Comment: @jpmc26 neither one of those address the use in a comparison predicate.

Answer (score 14):

```
 WHERE posn_id <> rid
```

Will return all rows where both `posn_id` and `rid` are not `NULL` and where they are different.

It's the ANSI SQL-Compliant `not equals operator` in a simple `comparison predicate` (`WHERE` statement). Colloquially, it's the *"inequality operator"*. Though many databases accept an alternative `!=`, the spec itself does not mention `!=` and it should not be used if `<>` is supported.

SQL uses [three valued logic](http://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic), with possible values being `true`, `false` or `unknown`. The `WHERE` clause filters out all rows except those where the predicate evaluates to `true`.

- If either or both sides are `null`, the operator returns `unknown`.
- On inequality, where both sides are not `=`, the operator returns true.
- On equality, `<>` returns false.

On null treatment, a similar operator is `IS DISTINCT FROM` which treats nulls as ordinary values, [from the PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html)

> For non-null inputs, `IS DISTINCT FROM` is the same as the `<>` operator. However, if both inputs are `null` it returns false, and if only one input is `null` it returns true.

For RDBMS specific documentation on comparison operators, see also

- [PostgreSQL comparison operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html)
- [IBM SQL comparison operators](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_61/sqlp/rbafycompop.htm)
- [SQL Server comparison operators `<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-traditional)
- [MySQL comparison operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

Comment: @KumarHarsh seriously, what are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

It's just another way of spelling the "not equals" operator, an alternative to `!=`

Comment: It's more accurate to say, "`!=` is another way of spelling `<>`" as `<>` is the only operator of the two defined by the ansi standard.

Comment: Not another way. In SQL is *the* way. `!=` was added later to please C programmers and was not standard for years

Comment: @edc65 It still isn't.